Why doesn't rotate() work when I translate my object?
I have an image in my webpage that I want to rotate, but it goes out of it's position and glitches out when I use both transform translate() and transform rotate(). I tried repositioning the lines of code but that did not work either. The image file name is "Rock.png".
The code I used:
Css:
#rock {
        content: url(Rock.png);
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

Html:
<div id="rock" onclick="rockFunc()"></div>


You can't use two transforms independently. Either merge them into a single declaration or use the more modern versions rotate/transform
